# AutoScale Watch brings incorrect data in Softlayer API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get trigger data, but the value of watch data bring wrong data.

```
        "algorithm": "EWMA",
        "id": 135609,
        "metric": "host.network.frontend.in.rate",
        "operator": ">",
        "period": 3600,
        "value": "10485760"
```

The value should be `80` instead of `10485760`. Do I need to convert the value with a proper unit ?

This is rest API I've used:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Scale_Group/1046365.json?objectMask=mask[id,+name,+status[name,+keyName],+regionalGroup[id,+name,+description],+suspendedFlag,+terminationPolicy,+cooldown,+regionalGroupId,+minimumMemberCount,+maximumMemberCount,+balancedTerminationFlag,+networkVlans[+id,+networkVlan[+id,+name,+vlanNumber,+networkSpace,+primaryRouter[id,hostname,datacenter[name,longName]],localDiskStorageCapabilityFlag,sanStorageCapabilityFlag]],virtualGuestMemberTemplate[hostname,domain,fullyQualifiedDomainName,startCpus,maxMemory,hourlyBillingFlag,localDiskFlag,operatingSystem,datacenter,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,networkComponents.maxSpeed,sshKeys,operatingSystemReferenceCode,blockDevices[device,diskImage.capacity],blockDeviceTemplateGroup.globalIdentifier,postInstallScriptUri],policies[id,cooldown,name,scaleActions[id,type[id,keyName,name],amount,scaleType],triggers[id,type],triggers%28SoftLayer_Scale_Policy_Trigger_OneTime%29[date],triggers%28SoftLayer_Scale_Policy_Trigger_Repeating%29[schedule],triggers%28SoftLayer_Scale_Policy_Trigger_ResourceUse%29[watches[id,algorithm,metric,operator,period,value]]],loadBalancers[id,port,healthCheck[id,attributes[value,type.keyname],type[id,keyname,name]],virtualServer[id,port,virtualIpAddress.ipAddress.ipAddress,virtualIpAddress.id,serviceGroups.routingType.name]],virtualGuestMemberCount]
```

Response Body :

```
   "triggers": [{
        "id": 163525,
        "type": {
            "id": 1,
            "keyName": "ONE_TIME",
            "name": "One Time"
        },
        "date": "2016-07-26T14:30:00+09:00"
    }, {
        "id": 163529,
        "type": {
            "id": 3,
            "keyName": "RESOURCE_USE",
            "name": "Resource Use"
        },
        "watches": [{
            "algorithm": "EWMA",
            "id": 135607,
            "metric": "host.cpu.percent",
            "operator": ">",
            "period": 1800,
            "value": "80"
        }, {
            "algorithm": "EWMA",
            "id": 135609,
            "metric": "host.network.frontend.in.rate",
            "operator": ">",
            "period": 3600,
            "value": "10485760"
        }, {
            "algorithm": "EWMA",
            "id": 138903,
            "metric": "host.cpu.percent",
            "operator": ">",
            "period": 7200,
            "value": "78"
        }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case of network rate the information in the API is being stored in bytes, and in the portal the information is being displayed in mega bits.

So do this:

```
converting bytes to bites

10485760 * 8 = 83886080

converting bites to kilo bites

83886080 / 1024 = 81920

converting kilo bites to mega bites

81920 / 1024 = 80
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks.. When I create or edit, the value should be converted to bytes. right?